# guardar formulario antes de enviarlo

Tags: php, javascript, php5

espero me puedan ayudar por favor.
Tengo un documento PHP llamado registro.php
Al principio tengo código en php para guardar verificar si ya inicio sesión, después de eso tengo mi HTML con 6 formularios, cada formulario representa un paso , muestro un ejemplo a continuación:

```
            <div id="DatosPersonales" class="contenidoPestania">       
                <form name="misDatos" id="misDatos" method="post" action="post.php">
                    <table>                     
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4"><h4 class="encabezado">Domicilio actual:</h4></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>Calle:</td><td colspan="4"><input tabindex="14" type="text" size="127" id="calle" name="calle" value="" required></td>
                            <td>No. Ext:<input tabindex="15" type="text" size="4" id="noExterior" required></td>
                            <td>No. Int:<input tabindex="16" type="text" size="4" id="noInterior"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>Colonia:</td><td colspan="3"><input tabindex="17" type="text" id="colonia" required></td>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>Municipio/Delegaci&oacute;n:</td><td colspan="2"><input tabindex="18" type="text" id="localidad" required></td>                       
                        </tr>                        
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>C.P.:</td><td><input tabindex="19" pattern="[0-9]{5,5}" id="cp" required></td>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>Entidad:</td><td colspan="2"><input tabindex="20" type="text" id="estado" required></td>
                            <td><span class="obligatorio">*</span>Pa&iacute;s:</td><td><input tabindex="21" type="text" id="pais" required></td>                            
                        </tr>         
                    </table>           
                </form>                    
                <br><a href='menu.php?u=<?php echo $usuario;?>'><input type='button' value='<<Regresar'></a>
                <input tabindex="22" type="button" id="btnSiguiente1" onClick="validarPaso1()" value="Siguiente>>"><br><br>
            </div>
```

Y los siguientes 5 formularios mantienen el mismo estilo, como pueden ver el Onclick sirve para que JS valide ciertas cosas, cabe mencionar que también va recibiendo los datos pues al final, JS es quien envía los datos de los 6 formularios.
El problema que tengo y espero me ayuden es que si voy en el paso 5 y actualizo la página, regreso al paso 1 y todos los datos se borran.
Mi duda es como puedo guardar esos datos en variables de sesión por ejemplo por si llego a actualizar los datos sigan ahí y solo tenga que dar siguiente y continuar hasta donde me quede.
Espero me puedan ayudar pues ya intente distintas formas y no logro solucionar mi problema
GRACIAS!!

Comment: ps una posible solución a tu problema, seria que cada vez que ejecutas el evento validarpaso1(), guardes en una cooke la información del formulario, para que cuando cargues esa pagina por primera vez, revises si hay una cooke y realices el proceso de llenar el formulario. Es lo único que se me viene a la mente a tu problema.

Comment: podrias ocupar session storage o local storage

Answer (score 0):

Session Storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

con javascript seteas el valor del input:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

y luego lo obtienes con:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```